# does YUI have selectors like in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, yui

Does `YUI` have selector methods like jQuery?

e.g. get me all div's that are `children` of `<table>` that have links in them?

Answer (score 7):

[YUI 3](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/) (currently in preview release) has explicitly JQuery-like selectors:

```
Y.all('.foo').set('title', 'Go!').removeClass('off');
```

Take a look at:

- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/node/nodelist.html
- http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/08/13/yui3pr1/

I've gotten good results using YUI 3 Preview Release 1 on [OffsetConsumer.org](http://www.offsetconsumer.org/), a website I'm working on; the next YUI 3 preview release is scheduled to come out in November.

Answer (score 5):

Check the [YUI Selector Utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/selector/), it gives you [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) selector sintax, it still in beta but works quite well, check this example: [YAHOO.util.Selector.query](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/selector/query.html)

Answer (score 1):

YUI has selector utility since version 2 (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/selector/), but it doesn't get popular in YUI 2 since most of module codes are written before selector is introduced into YUI2.